# Failed to deploy maven project in tomcat

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat, netbeans

When I execute mvn tomcat7:deploy ( and others things ) I always get the same issue:

```
[DEBUG] Connection manager shut down
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project WebGoat: Invocation de Tomcat manager impossible: Software caused connection abort: socket write error ->
[Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.1:redeploy (default-cli) on project WebGoat: Invocation de Tomcat manager impossible
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Invocation de Tomcat manager impossible
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:68)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:163)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.write(LoggingSessionOutputBuffer.java:74)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:119)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager$RequestEntityImplementation.writeTo(TomcatManager.java:856)
        at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:98)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:122)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:266)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:257)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:708)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:515)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:923)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:822)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:721)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:684)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.common.deployer.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:367)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:81)
        at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:132)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The problem is that I don't understand where the problem comes from.

My configuration on Maven is like this :

```
<server>
  <id>Catalina</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>admin</password>
 </server>
```

And the pom.xml of the project contains

```
<configuration>
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
<server>Catalina</server>
<path>/WebGoat</path>
<attachArtifactClassifier>exec</attachArtifactClassifier>
</configuration>
```

I have tried all the solutions that I found on stackoverflow and the internet.
thx for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

My friend resolved the problem. In fact, something was missing in the server.xml file. We added in the connector configuration maxSwallowSize="-1". And now everything is OKAY ! thx everybody

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

This looks like either tomcat is not running or not working properly - it closes connection before the data was actually uploaded. It would be worth checking the tomcat logs here.
Isn't the uploaded war too big so tomcat shutdowns the connection during the upload?

Try increasing tomcat upload size. Open webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml and change the following section:

```
<multipart-config>
     <max-file-size>60000000</max-file-size>
     <max-request-size>60000000</max-request-size>
     <file-size-threshold>0<</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work :( . We are missing something, for sure !!

Comment: Well, either check tomcat logs or if you're using Linux, you can use:
    strace -o trace.log -s 1024 -f mvn tomcat7:deploy  
and check file trace.log whether tomcat answers something useful or it just directly drops connection.